# ToolStripTextBox AutoSize Not Working

Tags: winforms, f#, cefsharp

I use the F# code below to read an input from a ToolStripTextBox.

My problem is that I could not make the ToolStripTextBox resize when the form is resized (like the URL field in a browser).

Any suggestions?

Among others I tried the suggestion in [this form](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d105edb5-2d25-49a0-8374-e12d23162f43/toolstriptextbox-autosize-not-working?forum=csharpgeneral) (with the right syntax), though it did not work.

My form is very similar to the code in the book ["Expert F# 3.0", page 429](http://books.google.it/books?id=66jOWQEvBMEC&pg=PA430&lpg=PA430&dq=%22ToolStripProgressBar(Size%20%3D%20new%20Size(200,%2016),%22&source=bl&ots=e30851aZ-t&sig=Y7Z5Ee9ufS1o3HzsheLQ_A-u754&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v7oqVJ3WL8K5OO_QgJgC&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22ToolStripProgressBar(Size%20%3D%20new%20Size(200%2C%2016)%2C%22&f=false).

```
open System.Windows.Forms


let form = new Form(Size=new Size(780, 560))

...       

let toolbar = new ToolStrip(Dock=DockStyle.Top, Name="Toolbar")
toolbar.Location <- new Point(50,25) 
...    
let input = new ToolStripTextBox(Size= new Size(600,25))

...

let go = new ToolStripButton(DisplayStyle=ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text,Text="Reduce",Visible=true)

toolbar.Items.Add(new ToolStripLabel("Input:")) |> ignore
toolbar.Items.Add(input) |> ignore
toolbar.Items.Add(go) |> ignore
```

Comment: I think there's nothing F# specific in the question. Does your code work in C# version? It looks like the problem with setting some property on Windows form control.

Comment: I am not used to programming in C#, hence F#. Though, to attack the problem, I fiddled quite a few properties, but without any success. My other fields of the form work fine (as expected) with the 'Anchor' property.

Comment: It turns out that the following code solves the problem. "form.ClientSizeChanged.Add ( fun arg -> input.Size <- new System.Drawing.Size(form.Size.Width - 160, 25))"

Comment: Great Ozan! Then please add your solution as answer to your own question and mark it as your preferred solution. Then everyone can see there's an answer resolving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code solves the problem:

```
form.ClientSizeChanged.Add ( fun arg -> input.Size <- new System.Drawing.Size(form.Size.Width - 160, 25))
```